# Using send() function in kamailio 4.4

Tags: kamailio

I'm trying to use the send() funcition in kamailio 4.4, but fail. The kamailio.cfg is loading fine without using send(), but when I add a send() in the request route, kamailio refuses to start with:

```
 ERROR: <core> [cfg.y:3231]: yyparse(): cfg. parser: failed to find command send (params 0) 0(30887) : <core> [cfg.y:3371]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 161, c..
```

Perhaps it has been removed, since it's available in the documentation for the core of older versions (p.e. https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/cookbooks/3.2.x/core#send), but not for 4.4 (https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/cookbooks/4.4.x/core#send).

Is the function still usable? If not, what replaced it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function has moved to the corex modules (http://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/4.4.x/modules/corex.html#corex.f.send). So send() can still be used by doing:

```
loadmodule "corex.so"
...
send()
```